# Prority asynch ques Implementation For books downloading

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

can any one tell me priority asynch ques implementation in ios ?

I want to implement download books from server with priority.

Answer (score 0):

Try NSOperation for this. You will have better control over process, can cancel operations and set priority and concurency.